# How to delete folder while deleting file inside it?

Tags: batch-file

Can we delete the folder too when deleting the file inside it using batch command.I have the file name buy not the folder name.So when my code deletes that file inside the folder i want the folder to be deleted as well,as its empty.

Code

String tmpfolder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c del "+tmpfolder+"IEDriver.dll /f /s /q");

This code deletes the file but not folder.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to delete the file? It is easier if we know how you are referencing it.

Comment: String tmpfolder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c del "+tmpfolder+"IEDriver.dll /f /s /q");

Comment: THe above code deletes the IEDriver.dll file but not the folder

Comment: Then why not change `del` command with `rd` command? Keep the `/s /q` switches and remove the `/f`

Comment: nop the folder is still there.but the file is deleted..the tempfolder path is C:\Users\biraj\AppData\Local\Temp\ and the folder which contain IEDriver.dll file name is webdriver100293.this folder name changes randomly so i cant take its static name.i only know that there is file name IEDriver.dll in those folder.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/179660/how-to-recursively-delete-directory-from-command-line-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"for /f \"delims=\" %a in ('dir /a-d /b /s \""+tmpfolder+"IEDriver.dll\"') do rd /s /q \"%~dpa\" \"");
```

This uses dir command to search for the dll and removes the folder in where it is stored.

Not tested.

Comment: nop the above command also didnt work. it didnt delete the file either